# Spring batch - File reader and writer with Multiple Headers and footers (ACH Format)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am currently looking into to develop batch jobs to read and write ACH files format.

Lets say its batch-job-file-import and batch-job-file-export and batch-job-scheduler

batch-job-file-import is responsible to read a file from an ftp location and update the records in database for each given detail record.

batch-job-file-export is responsible to read the records from database and write the file.

batch-job-scheduler is responsible to check in database if a scheduling time is reached for a config then launch jobs as sub jobs.

If you're familiar with ACH file format then its a pretty complex one.I have attached an image of format as well.

First write ACH Header

Then write Batch records which are broken down as below (one batch with out addenda and other with addenda) :

Batch Header
Entry Detail
Entry addenda(s) on a single entry detail
.
.
Batch control

Batch Header
Entry Detail(s)
.
.
Batch control

and in the end we got :
File Control

I have created few configuration tables to pick up the some the details to write in batch and header data and entry details are represented an API request which is stored in a separate db table.

I have created some simple batch jobs first and have some basic idea how Spring batch works.

I was looking in spring samples and found multi line jobs but these are no where near as complex to this one.

There are few thing which i need to understand any help is much appreciated :

1) I can create a header call back when job started which will write a file header but what i would need to do when i want to write individual batch headers and controls ?

2) When i query the database for records to write that means i have to load all the records in a model which has Header, batches and records with in it. Then i would loose chunk processing ?

3) As format to read and write is similar is there anything i can do to make most of the components shared ?

4) Given the records nature i have, would it be possible for me to use MultiLineRecordWriter and reader ?

[ACH File Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnZYc.png)

Comment: Hi
,were you able to solve this? I had a similar problem

Comment: Nope, for now I have used an ACH Libray, JACH. 

https://github.com/afrunt/jach